# How to set R1C1 style formula using Apache Poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm getting datas through JSON and generating Excel using Apache POI, When I use normal Formula "SUM(Q5:R5)" it works fine, but when I tried to use r1c1 reference formula SUM(RC[-2]:RC[-1]), it throws exception. I have referred Apache POI doc, and found Indirect method, but am not sure how to apply on my case. Can anyone help me in this issue.

Error Code: Caused by: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Specified named range 'RC' does not exist in the current workbook.

```
if(value[CELL_TYPE].equals("CELL_TYPE_FORMULA")) {
    String data = value[CELL_DATA];
    c.setCellFormula(data);
    c.setCellType(getCellType(value[CELL_TYPE]));
}
```

Am getting error while setting the cellFormula.

And this is the JSON Array data which am trying to set for the cell:
["SUM(RC[-2]:RC[-1])", "CELL_TYPE_FORMULA"]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can you provide more information including the code and errors you are getting.

Comment: You probably hit something that is not supported by Apache POI yet. Do you have a documentation-link with description how this "RC" stuff is handled by Excel? Or what would the expected result be?

Answer (score 0):

POI currently does not support R1C1 style cell references in formulas [per this documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/OperationEvaluationContext.html#getDynamicReference-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-).

Further, your syntax is wrong for R1C1 syntax - [see the description here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-formulas-34519A4E-1E8D-4F4B-84D4-D642C4F63263).  You use either R or C, not both at once.

Comment: I disagree about "You use either R or C, not both at once". The syntax is correct and it means "sum the cell on the left of the cell with the formula and the one on its left". If you replace SUM(RC[-2]:RC[-1]) with SUM(C[-2]:C[-1]) it means that you want to sum the content of the entire columns.